# Calculate an average value for each month

Tags: django, django-views

I try to calculate the average amount for each month for the 13 last month.

So I have a card with the date which has many amounts which are linked to a category.

For example my card 1 has an amount for category A, an amount for category B an amount for category C .... Amount, Card and Category have their own class in the model.

My objective is to calculate for one category, the average amount for each 13 last month.

Here is my model:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=False)
    day = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    comment = models.TextField(null=False)
    worked = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<id={}, date={}, day={}, comment={}, worked={}>".format(
        self.id,
        self.date,
        self.day,
        self.comment,
        self.worked
    )


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=False, unique=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return "<id={}, name={}, icon={}>".format(self.id, self.name, self.icon)


class Amount(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='amounts')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='amounts')

    def __str__(self):
        return "<id={}, amount={}>".format(self.id, self.amount)
```

And I have really no idea of how to do this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: A short (but not particularly satisfying) answer is: use raw SQL. The problem is that you're trying to aggregate data across _days_, which aren't objects, so the Django ORM can't help you much. (It's vaguely possible that you could figure out how to select the `Category` and have the ORM build 13 different aggregates with the data you want, but I suspect it would take longer to do that than to figure out the SQL and drop it into a custom `CategoryManager` then proxy that into a method on the `Category` object.)

Comment: You could start to do the calculations in Python (iterating over the QuerySet) and see how long that takes. If it is too expensive (in time, memory or other resources) then you can look into other options like Django aggregations or raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses Django's [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) and [Transform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/lookups/#transform-reference) to give you for one category called `category` the average of the amounts in each month in `range(13)`. If you need it to just be the previous 13 months I would suggest using `datetime.timedelta` and include a filter on card__date__year. You could also combine the filters below into one line but it gets a little long...

```
from django.db.models import Avg
amounts_in_category = Amount.objects.filter(category = category)
for month in range(13):
    amounts_in_month = amounts_in_category.filter(card__date__month = month)
    average_amount_for_month = amounts_in_month.aggregate(Avg('amount'))
```